# My application name is appearing incorrectly in Facebook's canvas app ticker

Tags: facebook, ticker

I have some question regarding fb app ticker, I already ask this question on facebook development forum but its been a few days now and to no avail.  You see, I have develop my very first facebook app called [MagMeUp](http://apps.facebook.com/magmeup/) but every time I use it, my app ticker on the top right corner of my screen is showing a different name.  I tested it on my brothers fb account and its just the same.  But whenever I change its name, eg. adding "z" at the end like "MagMeUpz" it shows as it is.  But when only "MagMeUp" it shows a different name.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the Facebook Linter to refresh the cache on your application and see if it helps.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Also make sure that you are using the correct appid and secret in your app.

Comment: waaa! that solves the problem :D it shows "MagMeUp" now on the app ticker :D Thanks a lot! :D I just enter on debug the app link and it solves it :D

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere (at least that I could find) and FB doesn't use this for any other display purposes as far as I know, but the ticker name seems to be pulled from the iframe's `<title>` element.

Comment: I set my app <title> tag to MagMeUp :(

Answer (score 0):

if your app url is  " http://apps.facebook.com/APPNAME/ "
facebook will visit this url to get the meta info ,  (og:title,og:description....)
i guess it will cache the meta info, 
use debug tool flush the cache seems not work, 
but you can modify you page, maybe:

http://apps.facebook.com/APPNAME/index.php, 
just change the index.php's content ,and all  ticker seems flushed !!!

if this not work, try  add